# Can I have 3 conditional statements in an if statement in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a tic tac toe game program and I need to check three cells of an array to check for a win. I wanted to write my code such that

```
if(cell1 == cell2 == cell3 ||
   cell4 == cell5 == cell6 || etc..) return true;
```

but it doesn't seem to let me include three conditional statements in one part. I know I could rewrite this code using &&, but is there a way to write a conditional statement with three things?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
  cell1 == cell2 == cell3
```

I assume these are integers.  Then `cell1 == cell2` yields a boolean result, and then you're trying to compare that boolean result to an integer, which isn't allowed and makes little sense.

You need `cell1 == cell2 && cell2 == cell3`.

By the way, that's one conditional expression, not three conditional statements. The conditional expression is part of an if statement.

Comment: Yeah my bad I just meant three parts in a conditional statement. I just thought there might've been a way to compare three integers at once.

Comment: You can always add helper subroutines to make code simpler.  Define a method ```boolean equal(int a, int b, int c)``` with the obvious body, and then you can write ```if (equal(cell1, cell2, cell3) || equal(cell4, cell5, cell6) ...)```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably take a more high level approach, because it tends to make things more manageable.

First, here's an enum of all valid winning sequences:

```
enum Sequence implements Function<int[],int[]> {
    TOP_ROW(0,1,2),
    MIDDLE_ROW(3,4,5),
    BOTTOM_ROW(6,7,8),
    LEFT_COL(0,3,6),
    MIDDLE_COL(1,4,7),
    RIGHT_COL(2,5,8),
    DOWN_DIAG(0,4,8),
    UP_DIAG(2,4,6);

    private final int[] positions;

    Sequence(final int ... positions) {
        this.positions = positions;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] apply(final int[] ints) {
        int[] cells = new int[positions.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = ints[positions[i]];
        }
        return cells;
    }
}
```

Now, assuming that your data model is an int[9] where all values are 0 (empty), 1 (player 1), or 2 (player 2), I'd use a method like this to check whether anyone has won (1 or 2 means the respective player has won, 0 means no one has won yet):

```
int winningPlayer(int[] game) {
    return Arrays.stream(Sequence.values())// for all known sequences
                 .map(s -> s.apply(game)) // extract the sequence from the game array
                 .filter(
                     // check whether all values are the same, and not neutral
                     a -> Arrays.stream(a).distinct().count() == 1 && a[0] > 0)
                 .findFirst() // if I find a matching array
                 .map(a -> a[0]) // then extract the player
                 .orElse(0); // otherwise return the neutral player

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but the ***syntax*** is verbose. Stream the three elements. Perform a distinct. Count the number of distinct elements. If it's less than 2 all of the elements are equal. Like,

```
if (Stream.of(cell1, cell2, cell3).distinct().count() < 2
        || Stream.of(cell4, cell5, cell6).distinct().count() < 2
        || etc... ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in an `if` statement, you can set more conditions but making it only an `if` statement would be better, you don't want `else if` in an `if` statement, that would only work outside the condition